# script to split file name into part1 and part2 and create directory part1 and put file part2 into part1 directory

Tags: python, linux, bash, split, directory

I have bunch of files of the form st_hwk.txt If you must know, this is how Moodle downloads assignments for grading. It takes the name of the hwk and prepands the user name.
This solution needs to work on Linux bc that is what I am working on.
Ex:
I download j smith_hwk1a.txt, j smith_hwk1b.txt, m wong_hwk1a.txt, m wong_hwk1b.txt. (yes the file names have fname space lname)

It should read the files names and create dir jsmith, and mwong. (no space)
Put into jsmith files hwk1a.txt  and hwk1b.txt. (the hwk1 that came from jsmith)
Put into mwong files hwk1a.txt  and hwk1b.txt. (the hwk1 that came from mwong).
You can use any tool on typical linux, bash, php, ...?
thank you

Comment: Please add the code which you have tried

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in *_hwk*.txt; do
  n=$(echo "$f"|tr -d ' '|tr _ /);   # delete spaces, convert _ to /
  mkdir -p "$(dirname "$n")";        # make directory if needed
  mv "$f" "$n";                      # move the file
done
```